# Extracting a value from jmeter response and exporting it to a csv file

Tags: jmeter

I need to know how can I extract a value from response in `jmeter` and export it to a csv file.

Suppose my response is like this:

```
<ns3:UpdateConsumerResponse
        xmlns:ns3="http://Pandora.NextGenCRM.Integrations.UpdateConsumerResponse"
        xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/" 
        xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Pandora.Xrm.DataModel.Request"
        xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Pandora.Xrm.DataModel.Response">
    <MasterConsumerID>
        CRM-CONID-000000519344
    </MasterConsumerID>
</ns3:UpdateConsumerResponse>
```

I need to extract the master consumer value and export it to an csv file.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to add an regular expression extractor as a child of this request
and then mention below inputs

> 1.Reference Name: MasterConsumer (or any variable)
>
> 2.Regular expression: abc(.*?)d (suppose your value is like abc`CRM-CONID-000000519344`d
>       then provided reg ex will work, now replace abc with your left
>       boundary and d with right boundary which you can get from your response. if still you need more help then
>       please provide this value along with more text from both side )
>
> 3.Template: $1$
>
> 4.Match No:1
>
> 5.Default Value: null

now you have your value stored in MasterConsumer variable (apply debug sampler to verify). Just you need to write into csv file, so add beanshell post processor as a child of same request and write below code for printing data into csv file

```
 MasterConsumer =vars.get("MasterConsumer");
 f = new FileOutputStream("Path"-Output.csv",true);
 p=new PrintStream(f);
 this.interpreter.setOut(p);
 p.println(MasterConsumer);
 f.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.i tried doing that way.but i could see only "null" in the csv file.the masterconsumer is not getting extracted properly.

Comment: in the debug sampler the masterconsumer variable has value as null

Comment: it means regular exp is not working properly. so please provide me the response containing the value to be extracted along with few words from both end i.e. provide boundaires

Comment: this is the response:

Comment: highlight which value you want to extract as I am unable to understand what exactly you want to extract here

Comment: <ns3:CreateConsumerResponse><MasterConsumerID>CRM-CONID-000000519356</MasterConsumerID>
</ns3:CreateConsumerResponse> this is the response i get.

Comment: i need to extract the masterconsumeid

Comment: <MasterConsumerID>(.*?)</

Comment: use this correlation and let me know if you are still getting error

Comment: its not working:(i tried that.are there any other ways that i can try?

Comment: As now, I can see your question properly (thanks to purplepsyco for editing), so reg ex for this will be <MasterConsumerID>([\s\S]+?)</

Comment: but in the csv file the value is still null

Answer (score 2):

1. Add [XPath Extractor](http://Using%20the%20XPath%20Extractor%20in%20JMeter) as a child of the request, which returns above value
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Check `Use Namespaces` box
   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `ID`
   - XPath query: `/ns3:UpdateConsumerResponse/MasterConsumerID/text()`
3. Add [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) **after** the XPath Extractor
4. Add the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   String file = "path_to_your_file.csv";
   String ID = vars.get("ID");
   String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(file),ID + newline, true);
   ```